# Take all the same elements from list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to take all elements which are the same, but only from the start, until it changes.

Example:

```cs
2,2,2,2,5,6,7,8,2,3
```

Result:

```
2,2,2,2
```

Example 2:

```cs
5,6,7
```

Result:

```
5
```

It's incredibly easy task to do without LINQ, but it will take more than one line of code. And I can't figure it out how to do it easily with LINQ.

Comment: What have tried so far and where did you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0):

```
var result = input.TakeWhile(x => x == input.First());
```

Comment: Brilliant. Now I'm trying to figure out how to do it with `Select`, since I'm using list of custom type.

Comment: @HPotts2 implement `IEquatable<YourType>` and then use `TakeWhile(x => x.Equals(input.First()))` - BTW this is why you shouldn't oversimplify your question

Comment: Managed to come up with solution. Marking as solved as soon as stack will let me. I'm wiriting my questions as easy as possible, its extremely easy to catch duplicate or closed question with 0 reasons.

Comment: The `input.First()` will be executed on every enumeration, so better if you just stored it in a variable. It could be an expensive query and there's no reason to evaluate it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
var a = new[]{2,2,2,2,5,6,7,8,2,3};

var start = a.TakeWhile(i => i == a[0]);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", start)); // 2,2,2,2
```